# Put a UIImagePickerController overlay in landscape

Tags: ios, camera, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to put correctly my overlay on landscape mode, so far this is what I have.:

[image: So the image appears, but it's not filling all the screen...]

So the image appears, but it's not **filling** all the screen on Landscape...

Here is some code:

```
- (IBAction)takeSecondPhotoAction:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *photoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    photoPicker.delegate = self;
    photoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        UIImageView * overlay;


        if(self.firstPhotoImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp || self.firstPhotoImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown){
            overlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
            [overlay setImage:self.firstPhotoImage];
            overlay.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57);
            [overlay setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        }else{
            overlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
            [overlay setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
            [overlay setImage:self.firstPhotoImage];
        }

        overlay.alpha = alphaValue;

        photoPicker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;


    [self presentViewController:photoPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

So basically, I ask first if the image is Landscape or Portrait, then I start filling in the image, asi you can see on landscape mode, first I rotate the overlay and then I assign the content mode.

So, I think the error is here: `[overlay setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];`

Is there any way to do this easily and properly?
Thanks

Comment: Use this - overlay.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Comment: @rishi not doing anything..

Comment: try changing setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit to scale to fill and see if that works.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey I tested it before, it only stretches the overlay.

Comment: then try setting the frame for overlay view manually something like the following [overlay setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 100, 260, 200)]; play with the size.